# wp_list_pages check if no children

Tags: wordpress

i am using custom walker on wp_list_pages , now i want to change value of $link and $checkchildren based on if they have children.

i want $linkcss and $checkchildren to be null if it has no children

```
$children = wp_list_pages(array(
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
    'title_li'    => '',
    'echo'        => 1,
    'walker' => new Sidebar_Custom_Walker()
));




class Sidebar_Custom_Walker extends Walker_Page {
    function start_el( &$output, $page, $depth, $args, $current_page = 0 ) {
        $output .= $indent . '<li class="rtChild">';
        $linkcss ="c1"; // should be blank if no children
        $output .= '<a href="' . get_permalink($page->ID) . '" class="'.$linkcss .'">' . $link_before;
        $output .= apply_filters( 'the_title', $page->post_title, $page->ID );
        $output .= $link_after . '</a>
        $checkchildren = '<span class="plusBtn"></span>'; // should be blank if no children
        $output .= $checkchildren;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to do this is to use the WordPress built-in function `get_pages()` inside the method `start_el`. Let's break this up:

First part:

```
<?php 

    class Sidebar_Custom_Walker extends Walker_Page {

        function start_el( &$output, $page, $depth, $args, $current_page = 0 ) {

            $output             .= $indent . '<li class="rtChild">';
```

The new part:

```
            // Retrieve page children with get_pages()
            // in combination with current $page->ID.
            $page_children       = get_pages( array('child_of' => $page->ID) );

            // Count amount of pages
            $page_children_count = count($page_children);

            // Does this page have children?
            if($page_children_count > 0){
                // Page has children
                $linkcss         = "c1";
                $checkchildren   = '<span class="plusBtn"></span>';
            }else{
                // Page has no children
                $linkcss         = null;
                $checkchildren   = null;
            }
```

And our output stays the same:

```
            $output  .=  '<a href="' . get_permalink($page->ID) . '" class="'.$linkcss .'">' . $link_before;
            $output  .=  apply_filters( 'the_title', $page->post_title, $page->ID );
            $output  .=  $link_after . '</a>';
            $output  .=  $checkchildren;

        }

    }


 ?>
```

I'm not sure whether it's good practice to nullify strings and then using them inside another variable as `$output` later.

Personally I would set them to empty:

```
 $linkcss       = "";
 $checkchildren = "";
```